# Why is my ethernet interface called enp0s10 instead of eth0?

Tags: linux, networking, udev, ethernet

When I run `ifconfig -a`, I only get **lo** and **enp0s10** interfaces, not the classical **eth0**

What does **enp0s10** mean? Why is there no **eth0**?

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated. Think about moving to `ip` from `iproute2` soon.

Comment: As the answer says it's a change in systemd. To get your `eth0` back use the kernel option `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` (see this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/741210/disabling-predictable-network-interface-names-in-xubuntu-15-10)). Using `ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rule` in below answer didn't work in Debian 10 (Buster)

Comment: @MrCalvin : the `ln -s ...` should be updated, see below

Answer (score 118, accepted):

That's a change in how now udevd assigns names to ethernet devices. Now your devices use the "Predictable Interface Names", which are based on ([and quoting the sources](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#n20)):

> 1. Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided index numbers for on-board devices (example: eno1)
> 2. Names incorporating Firmware/BIOS provided PCI Express hotplug slot index numbers (example: ens1)
> 3. Names incorporating physical/geographical location of the connector of the hardware (example: enp2s0)
> 4. Names incorporating the interfaces's MAC address (example: enx78e7d1ea46da)
> 5. Classic, unpredictable kernel-native ethX naming (example: eth0)

The why's this changed is documented in the [systemd freedesktop.org page](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/), along with the method to disable this:

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

or if you use older versions:

```
ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules
```

Comment: Following the freedesktop,org link, the main point is: `The classic naming scheme for network interfaces applied by the kernel is to simply assign names beginning with "eth" to all interfaces as they are probed by the drivers. As the driver probing is generally not predictable for modern technology this means that as soon as multiple network interfaces are available the assignment of the names is generally not fixed anymore and it might very well happen that "eth0" on one boot ends up being "eth1" on the next. This can have serious security implications...`

Comment: This  also applies to docker images. 
So trying to setup a network bridge between 2 docker networks caused problems 2 years ago because the network ports could be reversed on next boot.
an impossible situation for a bridge device.

Comment: funny enough, the "predictable name" of my ethernet device changed from `enp5s0` to `enp3s0` after a bios upgrade, rendering all my network configurations worthless...

Comment: @GaspardP I would say that that's a bug in your bios, how the device enumeration order on chip changed?!

Comment: Absolutely agree, this should not be common - the bus ids should not change and names should be predictable. I suspect this happened because my hardware was new and the bios was not yet able to detect everything connected. After upgrading, it probably discovered new devices. It might still be worth aliasing devices for some people, especially in the context of restoring a system backup onto different hardware.

Answer (score 236):

Answer on "What does enp0s10 means?" question:

```
enp0s10:
| | |
v | |
en| |   --> ethernet
  v |
  p0|   --> bus number (0)
    v
    s10 --> slot number (10)
```

Source: [udev-builtin-net_id.c on GitHub](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/ccddd104fc95e0e769142af6e1fe1edec5be70a6/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#L29)

Comment: Came looking for this.

Comment: Since there is no `...fN` part at the end of the NIC name, we can deduce that the function number is 0. After translating the numbers to hexadecimal (10 = "a" in hex), we know that `enp0s10` means PCI device ID `00:0a.0`.

Comment: There’s also https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.net-naming-scheme.html

Comment: This explains **eno** (onboard) **enp** (pci) and **enx** (mac.) But it does not explain the name **end**0. What does the d in end0 stand for?

Answer (score 44):

As mentioned above, enp0s10 refers to ethernet (en), prefix 0 (p0), slot 10 (s10).

The bus number, device number, and function number are pulled from the Bus Device Function (BDF) notation for PCI devices to create the prefix, slot, and function portions of the Predictable Network Interface Name (PNIN).

If the function is 0, the f0 portion is sometimes omitted. I changed the prefix from p0 to p4, and the function from f0 to f1, for clarity in this example. BDF uses hex values which get converted to decimal values in the PNIN.

Expanding on [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311844/86440) posted by [DIG mbl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/123606/dig-mbl):

```
enp4s10f1                        pci 0000:04:0a.1
| | |  |                                |  |  | |
| | |  |                   domain <- 0000  |  | |
| | |  |                                   |  | |
en| |  |  --> ethernet                     |  | |
  | |  |                                   |  | |
  p4|  |  --> prefix/bus number (4)   <-- 04  | |
    |  |                                      | |
    s10|  --> slot/device number (10) <--    10 |
       |                                        |
       f1 --> function number (1)     <--       1
```

https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Bus:Device.Function_(BDF)_Notation
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames

I came across a device with a u7 at the end, for USB port. Some of the different label possibilities are included in [this documentation on predictable network interface device names](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-understanding_the_predictable_network_interface_device_names).

A second example for the case where the PCI domain is something other than 0 (P stands for PCI geographical location):

```
P1enp4s10f1                        pci 0001:04:0a.1
| | | |  |                                |  |  | |
P1| | |  |  --> PCI geo loc/domain <-- 0001  |  | |
  | | |  |                                   |  | |
  en| |  |  --> ethernet                     |  | |
    | |  |                                   |  | |
    p4|  |  --> prefix/bus number (4)   <-- 04  | |
      |  |                                      | |
      s10|  --> slot/device number (10) <--    10 |
         |                                        |
         f1 --> function number (1)     <--       1
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```
net.ifnames=0
```

in kernel command line arguments and your interface name will be called `eth0` again.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  Where are the kernel command line arguments specified?

Comment: add this to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT section in /etc/default/grub. then run 'update-grub'.

Comment: This is terrible advice. It broke my system and is not a good habit.

Comment: how does it broke your system? 
you always can revert it by edit the kernel command line (press 'e' ) at boot time

Answer (score 2):

To quote the full text on disabling [linked by @Braiam](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/src/udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c#n20):

> #### I don't like this, how do I disable this?
>
> You basically have three options:
>
> 1. You disable the assignment of fixed names, so that the unpredictable kernel names are used again. For this, simply mask
>    udev's .link file for the default policy: `ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link`
> 2. You create your own manual naming scheme, for example by naming your interfaces "internet0", "dmz0" or "lan0". For that create your
>    own .link files in `/etc/systemd/network/`, that choose an explicit
>    name or a better naming scheme for one, some, or all of your
>    interfaces. See `systemd.link(5)` for more information.
> 3. You pass the `net.ifnames=0` on the kernel command line

TL;DR: it has been renamed to `99-default.link`

Comment: This doesn't work (any more?) in Fedora 39; with method 1 I get "wlan0" back but "eth0" remains a mangled name. Method 3 works, but feels less desirable somehow...