# how to get ethernet interface name, why do they vary from eth

Tags: firewall, ethernet, ifconfig

On a dell pc, the only ethernet interface off the motherboard shows up as **em1**.

On a newer supermicro server, the interface names are **enp137s0f0**

On some older supermicro servers, they are **eth0..eth3**

In setting up a firewall (RHEL/Centos 7) I need to create a zone and bind it with the correct interface name: eth0, em1, enp137s0f0.

In writing a script what is the best way on any given hardware, with the OS being RHEL/CentOS 7, to get the active interface name?

Why do they vary?  Is there a way to make everything just eth0..eth# ?

I need to do `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=mycustomezone --change-interface=???`

Comment: This is two questions in one.  The first has already been asked and answered several years ago at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134483/5132 .

Comment: There could be multiple active interfaces. If you look at the interfaces listed in `ip link`, is there one that you could programmatically choose? Would it be the first one after lo0? Would it be the one shown in `ip route show default` or `ip route get 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: One quick way to revert back to the old `eth0` style of interface names on some systems is to modify the boot loader commands with `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0`