# WASH command is blank - kali linux

Tags: kali-linux

I'm trying to follow a tutorial and he did `wash -i wlp2s0` and i have `wlan0` is there any difference?,
and if so is that the problem??

PS: its a tutorial on udemy

Comment: i followed a tutorial on udemy about that every thing was clear until the wlan0
and i dont know if there is any difference between those two

Comment: Which tutorial? Please [edit] your question to provide a link reference

Comment: @PhilipCouling `aircrack-ng`?

Comment: @AdminBee `aircrack-ng` might be a good alternative.  In any case it's a more helpful hint to future readers than directing them away from Kali.  [My own opinion on Kali](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5530/yet-another-kali-discussion-working-title) is that it's not a good tool generally.

Answer (score 2):

From google, `wash` is a penetration testing tool:

> [for identifying WPS enabled access points. It can survey from a live interface or it can scan a list of pcap files.](https://en.kali.tools/?p=341)

It looks like the tutorial is trying to scan for access-points using the machine's WiFi.  Historically most machines had their WiFi network interface named `wlan0`.

The author of the tutorial has used `wlp2s0` to mean your wireless card.  From your question it appears that `wlan0` is the real name of your WiFi interface.

There is no real difference between them, as far as they are just different names for the same thing on the authors machine vs your machine.

There is a reason why these names are changing:  Generally Linux distributions (including Kali) are moving to "Predictable Interface names" which an ironic name for a system that makes it nearly impossible to predict the name of an interface before it's connected.  You can read more about this here: [Why is my ethernet interface called enp0s10 instead of eth0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134483/why-is-my-ethernet-interface-called-enp0s10-instead-of-eth0)

---

*Side Note:*

If the command is not producing any results, and your not sitting in a field in the middle of nowhere then something might be wrong.  Kali usually makes you do everything as the user `root`.  It is unlikely this command would work if run as any other user.

Comment: thank u for explaining me this thing but its still errors

 ```Wash v1.4 WiFi Protected Setup Scan Tool
Copyright (c) 2011, Tactical Network Solutions, Craig Heffner <cheffner@tacnetsol.com>

[X] ERROR: Failed to open 'wlan0' for capturing
r```

Comment: @oryam I'm afraid that's beyond my knowledge to help.

Comment: now linux changed my ```wlan0``` to ```wlan0mon``` why is it happening

Comment: is it possible that my wifi card is not getting any wifi? and thats why im getting the blank wash?