# device names in rfkill output do not match those from ip

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, ip, devices

The devices listed by the rfkill command are completely different from the device names listed by the ip command:

```
> rfkill
ID TYPE DEVICE              SOFT      HARD
 0 wwan tpacpi_wwan_sw unblocked   blocked
 1 wlan phy0           unblocked   blocked
 8 wlan phy7           unblocked unblocked

> ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1d:28:4c:95:e6:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 22:5e:9b:23:24:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
25: wwp0s20u4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2e:e1:3b:d9:bc:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
26: wlxda2487111f99: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether da:24:87:11:1f:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Why is this, and how do I work out how they match up?

I read this post explaining how the device names used ip are assigned: [Why is my ethernet interface called enp0s10 instead of eth0?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134483/why-is-my-ethernet-interface-called-enp0s10-instead-of-eth0)
but how are the device names used by rfkill assigned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireless comes in two aspects:

- the wireless hardware device *phy*, usually named *phyX*.
- its associated network interface(s) *dev* usually named *wlanY*.

For a given wireless hardware device phyX, it's even possible to [create additional network interfaces associated to it](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw/vif), when it has the capabilities to do so. That's how it's possible for example to use the same card (when it has the capability) to be both a client and an access point at the same time. And that's probably why there's an additional layer. This lower layer is all managed with the `iw` command rather than the `ip link` command which controls only the final network interface.

Separately from this, the system can choose to rename (from *wlanY*) the *network interface* according to the so-called [*Consistent network interface device naming*](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/consistent-network-interface-device-naming_configuring-and-managing-networking#predictable-network-interface-device-names-on-the-x86_64-platform-explained_consistent-network-interface-device-naming) or also called [*Predictable Network Interface Names*](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). This is an unrelated topic, since it won't help any better to guess the association between *phyX* (which is typically dynamic) and *whatever* name.

`iw`'s man page is almost empty, but the command has still a (very) large help page.

```
# iw help | less

[...]
        dev
                List all network interfaces for wireless hardware.

        dev <devname> info
                Show information for this interface.
[...]
```

---

For a given network interface *wlanY*, using `iw dev wlanY info` will display in its results an entry called `wiphy` and an index. That's the index X of the matching *phy* interface. So you can get the *wlanY* -> *phyX* relation.

Example:

```
# iw dev wlan1 info
Interface wlan1
    ifindex 45
    wdev 0x300000001
    addr 16:c3:0c:a5:63:62
    type managed
    wiphy 3
    txpower 0.00 dBm
```

Or you can get the list of hardware devices sorted per phyX (displayed `phy#X`) with  their matching network interfaces. Eg:

```
# iw dev
phy#4
    Interface wlan2
        ifindex 46
        wdev 0x500000001
        addr 2a:5f:7f:7a:30:1b
        type managed
        txpower 0.00 dBm
phy#3
    Interface wlan1
        ifindex 45
        wdev 0x300000001
        addr 16:c3:0c:a5:63:62
        type managed
        txpower 0.00 dBm
phy#0
    Interface wlan0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr be:2d:23:03:29:c5
        type managed
        txpower 0.00 dBm
```

And *rfkill* displays the relation between *rfkillZ* and *phyX* (beside LTE modem and bluetooth).

```
# rfkill -o ID,TYPE,DEVICE,SOFT,HARD list
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 4 wlan      phy3   unblocked unblocked
 5 wlan      phy4   unblocked unblocked
 9 bluetooth hci0     blocked unblocked
```

---

By navigating through symlinks and reading contents available in `/sys/class/` the information is also available, in more than one possible way:

from *wlan* to *phy* to *rfkill*:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/net/wlan1/phy80211
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  1 20:58 /sys/class/net/wlan1/phy80211 -> ../../ieee80211/phy3
$ grep ^ /sys/class/net/*/phy80211/name 
/sys/class/net/wlan0/phy80211/name:phy0
/sys/class/net/wlan1/phy80211/name:phy3
/sys/class/net/wlan2/phy80211/name:phy4

$ ls -1d /sys/class/net/*/phy80211/rfkill*
/sys/class/net/wlan0/phy80211/rfkill0
/sys/class/net/wlan1/phy80211/rfkill4
/sys/class/net/wlan2/phy80211/rfkill5
```

from *rfkill* to *phy* to *wlan*:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill4/device
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Sep  1 21:05 /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill4/device -> ../../phy3
$ grep ^ /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill*/device/name
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/device/name:phy0
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill4/device/name:phy3
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill5/device/name:phy4
$ ls -1d /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill*/device/device/ieee80211/*
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/device/device/ieee80211/phy0
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill4/device/device/ieee80211/phy3
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill5/device/device/ieee80211/phy4
```

(the bluetooth device above has a different layout and is thus not displayed like this)

```
ls -1d /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill*/device/device/net/* 
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/device/device/net/wlan0
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill4/device/device/net/wlan1
/sys/class/rfkill/rfkill5/device/device/net/wlan2

# iw phy phy4 interface add onemorewlan type managed addr 12:34:56:78:ab:cd

$ ls -1d /sys/class/ieee80211/phy*/device/net/*
/sys/class/ieee80211/phy0/device/net/wlan0
/sys/class/ieee80211/phy3/device/net/wlan1
/sys/class/ieee80211/phy4/device/net/onemorewlan
/sys/class/ieee80211/phy4/device/net/wlan2
```

You get the idea.

Comment: OK, so there's actually at least 3 different devices associated with each wifi adapter: the physical device, the interface device(s), and the rfkill device. Is this correct?

Comment: Ah.. OK after a bit of googling what I surmise is that there is just one rfkill device (/dev/rfkill) which is used for interacting with the rfkill subsystem which assigns an ID (not a device per say) to each physical device. Not sure why rfkill uses a different number to the physical device number though.

Comment: rfkill handles wwan, wireless and bluetooth. There's no way it can keep the same numbering then if each of them also have their own numbering scheme.