# eth0 configuration missing on Oracle Linux | cabled connection not working

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, networkmanager, oracle-linux

I have installed Oracle Linux 7.9 on my laptop (not VM, just normal installation on an unused laptop). The WIFI connection works great, out of the box, no settings done beside just connecting to wifi. However, I want to connect this laptop to the internet via the Ethernet cable. I plugged in the cable and I know that the cable works for other pcs.

But, for whatever reason for this laptop it doesn't work. If i turn off the WIFI, i have no connection even with the ETH cable plugged in.

I did some digging and found out that my `eth0` connection is missing from `ifconfig` and even from `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`. Related to `eth`, I only have `ifdown-eth` and `ifup-eth` files in network-scripts.

I don't know much about networking, but I just can't figure out why the eth0 interface doesn't appear in ifconfig if I connect the cable and why it doesn't work out of the box.

This is my `ifconfig-a` result (with wifi on):

```
[root@oracle12c network-scripts]# ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 656  bytes 57832 (56.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 656  bytes 57832 (56.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:65:b6:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0-nic: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 52:54:00:65:b6:7d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::106a:5c19:5469:a40f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a02:a58:8225:5b00:7455:4696:10dd:27fe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b8:03:05:22:5c:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 485079  bytes 227481237 (216.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 662450  bytes 896474213 (854.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@oracle12c network-scripts]#
```

I've installed Network Manager TUI and if i go to `nmtui`->Edit a connection, under **Ethernet** section i have only `enp3s0`. However, from what i understood this is a default one. Also, if i go to nmtui->Activate a connection, I only have my WIFI discovered networks, if I have wifi running. If I turn off wifi, i don't have any other connection in here.

Also what is good to mention is that this is a pretty old laptop (~2012 or so) and I am not 100% sure that the ethernet adapter is working (hardwarely speaking).. If you can give me a way to figure out if it is working, it would be appreciated. Also, if you have a solution to this problem, how I can configure the eth0 interface so that it would work with the ethernet cable, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `eth0` has generally been [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134483/why-is-my-ethernet-interface-called-enp0s10-instead-of-eth0) in favor of more predictable names. `ens3p0` is your cabled port. Look in `dmesg` for any problems with the port.

Comment: Below is the link to the content for dmesg. I found nothing related to ens3p0.. Sorry but I don't know how to post a comment with newlines to show everything in order. Here is the link: https://fivemade.in/#E41NlNniyKlUeE8QZxJk